# best way to setup an index for this particular query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have a DB with about 2 million rows and I need to fix my current paging and have decided to go with the following:

```
SET @startRowIndex = ((@Page-1) * @PageSize) + 1; 

    SET ROWCOUNT @startRowIndex
    SELECT @first_id = ProductID FROM LiveProducts (nolock) WHERE ManufacturerID=@ManufacturerID AND ModifiedOn >= @tStamp ORDER BY ProductID

    SET ROWCOUNT @PageSize
    SELECT * FROM LiveProducts (nolock) WHERE ManufacturerID=@ManufacturerID AND ProductID >= @first_id ORDER BY ProductID
```

I am no where near a DBA and I want this to be as fast as possible.  What index(s) shoud i set on this thing.  From my reading and my basic understanding I gathered I should create a no-clustered index on ManufacturerID, ProductID, and ModifiedOn.

But should they all be `Index key column`s, or just one there and the others in `Included Columns`?

Comment: Your paging logic makes no sense. The first query will not even work as written b/c you cannot do a scalar assignment if the query returns >1 rows. You probably want to say "@first_id" = MAX(ProductID). Your second query has a different WHERE clause than your first query. You at least need to include ModifiedOn >= "@tStamp" in the 2nd query to get consistent paging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first query uses the following columns:  `ProductId`, `ManufacturerId`, and `ModifiedOn`.

Because you have an inequality on the date, the index can be used to optimize the `where` clause but not the `order by`.  However, by including the `ProductId` in the index, the engine can satisfy the entire query using the following index:  `LiveProducts(ManufacturerId, ModifiedOn, ProductId`).  Note that the ordering of these columns is important.  And, the query will still need to do a sort for the `order by`.

The second query is selecting all columns, so it need to go to the original data.  So, the optimization is on the `where` clause only.  For this, use `LiveProducts(ManufacturerId, ProductId)`.  In this case, it should be able to use the index for the sort.

Comment: so I need to create 2 indexes?

Comment: @Slee . . . Well, for optimal indexing for two queries, you do need two indexes.  Depending on which query needs more performance improvement, you might choose to have only one.